# Scala code to read each line from a file not working as expected

Tags: scala

I  am trying to read  all lines in a file .

But when i try to use the same variable, i am not getting any output

Please look at my below code.

```
 scala> import scala.io.Source
 import scala.io.Source

scala> val lines = Source.fromFile("/home/inputfiles/records.txt").getLines
lines: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator

scala> for(i <- lines)
 | {
 | println(i)
 | }
 100,Surender,CHN
 101,Raja,CHN
 102,Vikram,BNG
 103,Vijay,MUM

 scala> for(i <- lines)
 | {
 | println(i)
 | }
```

Why  i am not getting any output  at second time when i applied the same for loop logic on same variable .

I want to store  each line in  any collection.

hence i tried using ArrayBuffer..

```
scala> var myArray = ArrayBuffer[String]()
myArray: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[String] = ArrayBuffer()

scala> val lines = Source.fromFile("/home/inputfiles/records.txt").getLines
lines: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator

scala> for(i <- lines)
 | {
 | myArray += i
 | }

 scala> myArray
 res18: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[String] = ArrayBuffer(100,Surender,CHN, 101,Raja,CHN, 102,Vikram,BNG, 103,Vijay,MUM)
```

But I would like to store each line in a List . How do i achieve that?

Comment: Because using an iterator to the end empties it. So after the first for-loop, the iterator is empty. Either re-open the file, or store the lines in a List or something

Comment: Ok. I tried to store each line in ArrayBuffer. but i want to Store  each line is List .. Is that Possible?

Comment: Of course. `Source.fromFile("/home/inputfiles/records.txt").getLines.toList`

Comment: Great. I tried that as per your suggestion and got it. Thanks Much!!